# How use Word 2007 VBA to copy all text and replace it into a for rows csv document

Tags: vba, csv, ms-word, word-2007

How use Word 2007(or Word 2003) VBA to copy all text and paste it into a four rows csv document. For example: "I love the world". It will be:

```
I -    Line 1 - page 1 - Paragraph 1
love - Line 1 - page 1 - Paragraph 1
the -  Line 1 - page 1 - Paragraph 1
word - Line 1 - page 1 - Paragraph 1
```

Comment: Copy all text from a Word document, or from somewhere else? You mention a "single-column" csv file, but your Access table description seems like multi-column...

Comment: Please keep in mind that when using an MS Access database the maximum amount is 255 columns per table (as far as I remember).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should output to .csv file.

**Note! First, please add reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime dll (scrrun.dll)**:

From the VBA window Tools->References->Check Microsoft Scripting Runtime dll

Here is the code that works (you can create macro and place the code inside it):

```
Dim wordsArray, arrayElement
Dim delimiter As String
Dim fileName As String
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim outputFile As textStream

'select all document's content
ActiveDocument.Select

'provide delimiter
delimiter = InputBox("Please enter delimiter to use")

'split the selected content and place it inside the array
wordsArray = Split(Selection.Text, delimiter)

'generate output file name
fileName = "C:\Output.csv"

'create new FileSystem object and open text stream to write to
Set fs = New FileSystemObject
Set outputFile = fs.CreateTextFile(fileName, True) 'note file will be overwritten

'iterate through array and write to the file
For Each arrayElement In wordsArray
    'Use the following code to place each word into separate COLUMN
    'outputFile.Write (arrayElement) & ","

    'Use the following code to place each word into separate ROW
    outputFile.WriteLine (arrayElement)
Next

'close output stream
outputFile.Close
```

You can massage it based on your needs...

Hope this helps.

Comment: This code not helped. This code paste all text (equal original word file)into csv file. Each row with one word.

Comment: The code actually does what you asked for "This will be like: first column (I); second column (love)..etc". With all the controversy in your question, I thought last words were exactly what you were looking for...

Comment: Eureka!!! The code Worked. I made little adaptacions in your code: 1)I disable 'delimiter = InputBox("Please enter delimiter to use")';2)Change to 'wordsArray = Split(Selection.Text, " ")';3)Change to 'outputFile.Write (arrayElement) & vbCrLf'.

Comment: @jbofelli Would you mind marking my answer as the best since it worked and did what you asked for? One note, though. Row IS NOT a column. When you add Carriage Return and/or Line Feed characters to the end of the line (vbCrLf), you, actually, create new ROW not COLUMN...

Comment: @jbofelli You posted your second question as an answer. This prevents some users (myself included) from responding to it due to lack of reputation points. I would suggest posting it as a separate question on stackoverflow.

Comment: Sorry My English.Correcting what was said earlier, I refer to row and not column. I will post a separate question.

Comment: @jbofelli Thank you! could you please mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer. Thanks again!